# What are the equivalent of RibbonRadioButton in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

In Microsoft Ribbon Control, there is RibbonRadioButton where we can use on the Ribbon tab.

[image]

Are there equivalent in DevExpress WPF Controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an equivalent of RibbonRadioButton you can use the [BarCheckItem](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfBarsBarCheckItemtopic). Bar check items can be combined into a group via the [GroupIndex](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfBarsBarCheckItem_GroupIndextopic) property. Checking one item within a group automatically unchecks the other items. For more details, please read this article: [The List of Bar Items and Links](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6646)
P.S. Check if [DevExpress Search Engine](http://search.devexpress.com) is able to answer questions faster than I do.